How to Rewrite a Polynomial as a Sum of Two Squares Using Python?
I need help rewriting the following algebraic expression using Python
Given the input expression:
x**2 - 2*x*y + 2*y**2 + 2*x - 10*y + 17

The output should be the sum of two squares:
(x - y + 1)**2 + (y - 4)**2

Is there a way or function to input the expression and get the output as the sum of squares using Python?

This sounds like something sympy may be able to do.

Seeing how even wolframalpha does not list sum of two squares as an alternative form, I doubt there is a widely known library in Python that does exactly that.
Most probably you will have to get your hands dirty and write a program specifically for the case. When the input and output are known to be small integers (or some other very restricted set of values), brute forcing over a, b, c, d, e, f in the expression (a*x + b*y + c)**2 + (d*x + e*y + f)**2 should work.
Instead of manipulating the symbols, you can use eval builtin function and check for equality with several different values of x and y. If they are indeed equal every time, we can utilize Schwartz-Zippel lemma to say the result is probably correct.
